# Ruby and TkText

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I need to get data from text fields. I used TkText but could not pass it the argument 'textvariable'. This argument only works for Tk::Tile:Entry is a single line in height, and I need 3. I went to change settings for :rowspan when rendering 'Entry' widget, but it did not help.

```
$message = TkVariable.new
text = Tk::Tile::Entry.new(content) {
    textvariable $message # not worked in TkText :(
    width 1
    font TkFont.new('bold times 12')
    pack('side' => 'left', 'padx'=> '0', 'pady'=> '0')
}
```

How it to make?

Comment: no solutions? help me pls!!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The text widget has a `get` method, which takes two indices that describe a region to get. The first character is the string `1.0`, and the last character is the string `end-1c` (technically, the last character in the widget is `end`, but tk always adds an extra newline at the end which you normally don't want to get)

My ruby is very rusty, but I think this will work:

```
data = text.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
```